Implementing producer consumer process using two pipes
I need to implement a producer/consumer process including two ordinary pipes. The producer has the task to take input string from the user, change it to the binary format, and send it through a pipe to consumer. Consumer receives it change the binary format to string, if the strings are in lowercase change it uppercase and send back to producer through another pipe. I need to use exec() system call to access the services such as convert sting to binary, converting to uppercase etc.
I create two c files to implement each function. Such as chartobinary.c has the code block:
#include "mylib.h"

char* charToBinary(char c, char* b) {
    
    b[7]='\0';
    for(int i = 6; i>=0; i--){
        b[i]=(c & 1)? '1' : '0';
        c >>= 1;
    }
    return b;
}

Also implemented a service for charToBinary such as:
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include "mylib.h"  
    
    int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        if (argc != 2) {  
            fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <character>\n", argv[0]);
            return 1;
        }
    char b[8];  // Buffer to store the binary representation
    char* result = charToBinary(argv[1][0], b);  // Convert the character to binary
    printf("%s\n", result);  // Output the binary string

    return 0;
}

Same thing applied for uppercase function implementation.
The producer code for this purpose is:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include "mylib.h"  // Include function prototypes



// Function to send data through a pipe using exec() to convert to binary
void callCharToBinaryService(char c, char* binary) {
    int pipefd[2];
    if (pipe(pipefd) == -1) {
        perror("pipe failed");
        exit(1);
    }

    int pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0) {  // Child process
        close(pipefd[0]);  // Close reading end
        dup2(pipefd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);  // Redirect stdout to the pipe
        close(pipefd[1]);

        char charArg[2] = {c, '\0'};  // Convert char to string
        execl("./charToBinaryService", "charToBinaryService", charArg, NULL);  // Call the service

        perror("execl failed");
        exit(1);
    } else if (pid > 0) {  // Parent process
        close(pipefd[1]);  // Close writing end
        wait(NULL);  // Wait for the child process to finish
        read(pipefd[0], binary, 8);  // Read binary result from the pipe
        binary[7] = '\0';  // Null-terminate the binary string
        close(pipefd[0]);  // Close reading end
    }
}

int main() {
    int pipeProducerToConsumer[2], pipeConsumerToProducer[2];

    // Create two pipes
    if (pipe(pipeProducerToConsumer) == -1 || pipe(pipeConsumerToProducer) == -1) {
        perror("pipe failed");
        exit(1);
    }

    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0) {
        perror("fork failed");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (pid == 0) {  // Child process (Consumer)
        close(pipeProducerToConsumer[1]);  // Close writing end of Producer → Consumer pipe
        close(pipeConsumerToProducer[0]);  // Close reading end of Consumer → Producer pipe

        
        execl("./consumer", "consumer", NULL);  

        perror("exec failed for consumer");
        exit(1);
    } else {  // Parent process (Producer)
        close(pipeProducerToConsumer[0]);  // Close reading end of Producer → Consumer pipe
        close(pipeConsumerToProducer[1]);  // Close writing end of Consumer → Producer pipe

        // Open the input file
        FILE* inputFile = fopen("input.txt", "r");
        if (!inputFile) {
            perror("Error opening input file");
            exit(1);
        }

       
        Sendbinary(pipeProducerToConsumer, inputFile);

        //Receive binary and change to uppercase data from the consumer
        char buffer[256];
        close(pipeConsumerToProducer[1]);  // Close writing end
        while (read(pipeConsumerToProducer[0], buffer, sizeof(buffer)) > 0) {
            printf("Received from consumer: %s\n", buffer);  // Display received data
        }
        close(pipeConsumerToProducer[0]);

        fclose(inputFile);
        wait(NULL);  // Wait for the consumer process to finish
    }

    return 0;
}

The content of mylib.h:
#ifndef ENDEC_H
#define ENDEC_H

char* charToBinary(char c, char* binary);
char toUpper(char c);

#endif 

For the consumer part the code block is as follows:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include "mylib.h"  // Include function prototypes



// Function to call toUpperService using exec()
void callToUpperService(char* data) {
    int pipefd[2];
    if (pipe(pipefd) == -1) {
        perror("pipe failed");
        exit(1);
    }

    int pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0) {  // Child process
        close(pipefd[0]);  // Close reading end
        dup2(pipefd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);  // Redirect stdout to the pipe
        close(pipefd[1]);

        execl("./toUpperService", "toUpperService", data, NULL);  // Call the toUpperService executable

        perror("execl failed");
        exit(1);
    } else if (pid > 0) {  // Parent process
        close(pipefd[1]);  // Close writing end
        wait(NULL);  // Wait for the child process to finish
        
        // Initialize data buffer before reading
        memset(data, 0, sizeof(data));
        
        read(pipefd[0], data, MAX_FRAME_SIZE);  // Read the uppercase result from the pipe
        data[MAX_FRAME_SIZE - 1] = '\0';  // Null-terminate the data
        close(pipefd[0]);  // Close reading end
    }
}
int main() {
    int pipeProducerToConsumer[2], pipeConsumerToProducer[2];

   
    // Step 1: Receive  from producer, process it, and send back
    receivefromproducer(pipeProducerToConsumer, pipeConsumerToProducer);

    return 0;
}

Can I use separate c programs for producer and consumer process? The producer and consumer depends upon each other. So, if they are in separate file how this synchronization will be implemented? In the producer part I wrote  execl("./consumer", "consumer", NULL); but if I compile the producer first then it would not expect a executable from consumer. How to handle that part?

"There are errors in implementing the producer and consumer codes."  Such as?

char charArg[2] = {c, '\0'};  // Convert char to string is easier to both write and understand as char charArg[] = "c";

where is the definition of receivefromproducer()? Why are you using environment variables if the pipes are connected to stdin and stdout?

@ScottHunter The producer and consumer code were not complete. I give an overview what can be implemented based on my understanding.

?@AndrewHenle can you please elaborate on that?

@AndrewHenle those two bits aren't equivalent.

Figuring out how to proceed is the purpose of the exercise.  If you have specific questions about how the C language or standard library works, or about specific details of your code failing to compile or behaving differently than you expect, then we can probably help, but giving you step by step instructions would make it our homework (which I, for one, do not need).
